# APP Script list Google Drive files in Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-drive

I've been on a hunt to find a script that will return file names and hyperlinks into a Google Sheet.  I found the following script that works perfectly, but is limited to PDFs.  How do I modify this so it returns all files within a given folder?

```
function ListFldPdfs() {
  // replace FOLDER-ID with your folder's ID
  // replace SHEET-NAME with the name of the sheet that will hold the list
  var myPDFfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER-ID'); // replace FOLDER-ID with your folder's ID
  var thesheet = 'SHEET-NAME' // give a name to YOUR list sheet

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newPDFsheet = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet); 
     if (!newPDFsheet) { 
       ss.insertSheet(thesheet, 0); 
       var newPDFsheet = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet) ;
  Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName());
     }
  // clear all existing content
  newPDFsheet.clear();
  // append the header row
  newPDFsheet.appendRow([ "Name", "VIEW", "HYPERLINK"]);
  var results = [];
  // list all pdf files in the folder
  var mypdfs = myPDFfolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
  // loop through found files in the folder
  while (mypdfs.hasNext()) { 
    var myfile = mypdfs.next(); 
    var fname = myfile.getName();
    var furl = myfile.getUrl();
    results = [ fname, furl, ];
    //Logger.log("results = "+results); // for de-bugging
    newPDFsheet.appendRow(results); 
       } 
     var fcell = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet).getRange("C2"); 
               fcell.setFormula('=arrayformula(if(A2:A10="",,hyperlink(B2:B10,""&A2:A10&"")))'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
  var mypdfs = myPDFfolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
```

...use [Folder.getFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfiles), like this:

```
  const myFiles = myPDFfolder.getFiles();
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, here's the updated script:

```
'function ListFldFiless() {
  // replace FOLDER-ID with your folder's ID
  // replace SHEET-NAME with the name of the sheet that will hold the list
  var myFilesfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER-ID'); // replace FOLDER-ID with your folder's ID
  var thesheet = 'SHEET-NAME' // give a name to YOUR list sheet

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newFilessheet = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet); 
     if (!newFilessheet) { 
       ss.insertSheet(thesheet, 0); 
       var newFilessheet = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet) ;
  Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName());
     }
  // clear all existing content
  newFilessheet.clear();
  // append the header row
  newFilessheet.appendRow([ "Name", "VIEW", "HYPERLINK"]);
  var results = [];
  // list all files in the folder
  const myFiles = myFilesfolder.getFiles();
  // loop through found files in the folder
  while (myFiles.hasNext()) { 
    var myfile = myFiles.next(); 
    var fname = myfile.getName();
    var furl = myfile.getUrl();
    results = [ fname, furl, ];
    //Logger.log("results = "+results); // for de-bugging
    newFilessheet.appendRow(results); 
       } 
     var fcell = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet).getRange("C2"); 
               fcell.setFormula('=arrayformula(if(A2:A10="",,hyperlink(B2:B10,""&A2:A10&"")))'); 
}'
```